# Azure API Management custom subscriber settings / preferences

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to store custom settings at the level of a subscriber? I see that there is a `Property` object, but it does not seem to be a subscriber-level object.

I also see the identities array for every `User`, which is probably free for taking, but it's not by design.